# video streaming with flask, multiprocessing, CPU usage capped to single core level

Tags: opencv, flask, video-streaming, flask-socketio

I'm trying to use flask to do video streaming, following the instructions of https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/video-streaming-with-flask. It's working, but I noticed a few things, and some strange behaviors with respect to multiprocessing.

Below is the code. A background process gets from the camera feed and saves the frames in a shared array `frame`. The foreground loop encodes the frame array into `.jpg` bytes. A web server runs in a background daemon thread, and route `/video_feed` sends a long-connecting multipart response.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Lock, Value, Array
from threading import Thread
import sys
import ctypes
import numpy as np
import cv2
from flask import Flask, render_template, Response, request
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, send, emit

SCREEN_WIDTH = 1280
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 720

frame = np.ctypeslib.as_array(Array(ctypes.c_uint8, SCREEN_HEIGHT * SCREEN_WIDTH * 3).get_obj()).reshape(SCREEN_HEIGHT, SCREEN_WIDTH, 3)
stopped = Value(ctypes.c_bool, False)

def get_from_stream():
    stream = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    stream.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, 30)

    while True:
        if stopped.value:
            stream.release()
            return

        _, frame_raw = stream.read()
        frame[:] = frame_raw

Process(target=get_from_stream).start()

# web server
app = Flask(__name__)
# socketio = SocketIO(app, async_mode=None)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

def gen():
    while True:
        yield (b'--frame\r\n'
               # b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame_bytes + b'\r\n\r\n')
               b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame_marked)[1].tobytes() + b'\r\n\r\n')

@app.route('/video_feed')
def video_feed():
    return Response(gen(),
                    mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')

# @socketio.on('quit')
# def quit():
#     stopped.value = True

thread_flask = Thread(target=app.run, kwargs=dict(debug=False, threaded=True))  # threaded Werkzeug server
# thread_flask = Thread(target=socketio.run, args=(app,), kwargs=dict(debug=False, log_output=True))  # eventlet server
thread_flask.daemon = True
thread_flask.start()

while True:
    if stopped.value:
        sys.exit(0)
    frame_bytes = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)[1].tobytes()
    frame_marked = frame
```

The commented-out code sections show my experiments. I noticed that if the generator `gen()` gets the already encoded (by the main loop) `frame_bytes`,

```
b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame_bytes + b'\r\n\r\n')
```

instead of encoding it right inside of the generator,

```
b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame_marked)[1].tobytes() + b'\r\n\r\n')
```

the total CPU usage gets consistently below 100% on a dual-core Macbook Pro, **if `/video_feed` is being visited**. If no one is visiting `/video_feed`, or someone is visiting but the generator encodes the frames itself, the main process takes 90+% CPU and the background `get_from_stream` takes 20%, in total bigger than one core usage level.

I can be sure this is not due to imprecision of CPU usage estimates (`htop`), and if there is some other background processes consuming a lot of CPU, the same capping happens to those processes as well so the total CPU usage is below 100%, again, if `/video_feed` is being visited and the generator gets the already encoded `frame_bytes`.

The same appears to the flask-socketio server with eventlet installed and automatically switched on. In addition, when I comment out those lines and run the eventlet server, when encoding frames in the generator, only one feed request can be processed, all other page visits and socketio messages are essentially blocked. When I restart the program, those blocked socketio messages get processed, as I haven't refreshed the page and they must have been queued somewhere on the frontend. This is unique to the eventlet server, because when I used the threaded Werkzeug server above, multiple page/feed requests can happen at the same time, although each feed encodes frames on its own, resulting in very big CPU consumption (total close to dual-core level). **But**, with the eventlet server, when the above CPU capping is taking place (generator getting `frame_bytes`), multiple requests (multiple page/feed requests at the same time), and socketio messages are processed asyncly without problem.

The deal with flask-socketio is just something related that occurred during my trial-and-error. The main problem is there with the plain Werkzeug server. I wouldn't want to let each `/video_feed` request encode frames on its own, would I? It seems trivial to have that view function directly get the encoded bytes, but it's just strange that total CPU capping is taking place affecting other processes.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very interesting problem.

In approach #1, you have the main thread encode the raw video frames to jpeg, and the video stream thread deliver those to the client.

In approach #2, you have the main thread just store the raw video frames, and the video stream thread encodes and delivers the frames to the client.

You would think that #1 should be equal or faster than #2 when you have a single client watching the stream, but your tests (and mine here as well) show that approach #2 is more efficient in terms of CPU usage.

What you did not take into account is the rate at which the threads encode frames. In approach #1 the main thread encodes jpeg frames as fast as it can, regardless of the frame rate of the camera, and the frame rate encoded frames can be pushed to the client. The video feed thread has nothing to do other than pushing frames to the client, so it can run much faster than the main thread and push duplicate frames, which just add overhead without any benefit. In approach #2, the encoding of jpeg frames is slowed down by the network writes, so overall less frames are encoded per unit of time, spending less CPU.

I think the changes you need to make for #1 to be as efficient as it can be are two:

- Make sure you only encode jpeg frames at a rate no faster than the frame rate of the camera.
- Make sure the video feed only pushes a new frame to the client at a rate no faster than the rate the main thread is encoding frames.

So basically, you need to add signaling mechanisms. The opencv capture thread should signal the main thread when a new frame was captured. The main thread then should encode the frame, and signal the video feed thread to deliver it to the client. You can use [Event](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/threading.html#event-objects) objects for these signals, for example.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I don't think it's the main thread over-encoding though. The encoding takes 70 ms for a frame, 14 fps. And when I use approach #1, but still leave the encoding part in the main loop uncommented, the CPU usage is beyond 1-core level. It is only when I actually start a page and visit `/video_feed`, suddenly total CPU drops to 1-core level. When I close the page, CPU usage is up again.

Comment: Too see it more prominently, try `Process(target=do_nothing).start()` where `do_nothing` is `while True: pass`. Watch total CPU initially being 200%, and drops to 100% when `/video_feed` is visited. (in approach #1). I'm not sure how to control the rate of `Response(gen())` and it seems to be the key here.

Comment: I didn't say that the main thread is over-encoding in this specific case. All I'm saying is that your solution #1 does not protect against that, in the same way it does not protect against pushing duplicate frames to the client. As I said in my answer, you need to add signaling, so that frames are processed only at the right times, both in the main thread and in the video feed generator function.

Comment: OK. Will do that.

Comment: I have a proof of concept build of my repo that implements signals. With one client watching the stream, CPU usage goes from 45% down to 12%. A second clients brings CPU to just 15%. I'll write a new blog post to describe this, as it ended up being not totally trivial.

Comment: Sounds good. This is surely something that deals better with updating shared state changes. On the other hand, I hope I described the behavior in this post clearly. I actually wanted the CPU usage to be higher than 1-core, because for some reason when `/video_feed` is visited in approach #1, other background processes CPU usage is also capped so that total usage is ~100%, not 200% or other. When it comes to a multi-core machine, I would want to use more than one core.

Comment: No, sorry, that I did not understand that. Why would you want higher CPU usage anyway? I think the reason approach #1 uses less CPU is that the GIL creates some lock contention, between the encoding happening in one thread and the streaming happening in another. Approach #2 puts both tasks together in the streaming thread, so in that case the GIL is not in the middle.

Comment: Because for some reason it also affects other **processes**, capping CPU so that total usage of the entire program is below 100%. When the background process is doing something important, I would want it to run at comparable fps as the frames from stream fps. The GIL argument works for the main process consisting of the main thread loop and `/video_feed` serving thread but other processes are also mysteriously affected and I don't know why. See comment 2: > Too see it more prominently...

Comment: You are comparing the app's state before a client connects (200% CPU) to after (100% CPU). That is not a fair comparison. When no users are connected, your app is basically a huge busy loop, partly from the camera encoding, partly for this do_nothing process. When a client connects, there is a fairly high amount of I/O in the system. That affects the dynamics of your processes and threads. Also note that I do not see a 100% cap here with your script. I get numbers between 130% and 190% myself.

Comment: Thanks for the discussion. That's interesting. My test shows, when there is a user watching `/video_feed`, it's 100% screenshot http://astro1.panet.utoledo.edu/~terencezl/ext/visit.png, when there is no user, it's 200%, http://astro1.panet.utoledo.edu/~terencezl/ext/no-visit.png. It's fairly consistent. My ultimate goal is to let other background processes, like `do_nothing` run fast, that's all... I'll keep looking into it.